# Mysql insert/updates in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am not sure how to handle this, if there is any kind of way the required zeroes are inserted or I should insert them by hand. This is a query I need to do:

```
connection.query('UPDATE devices SET wake="'
            + wake_hour  + ":" + wake_minute+':00",      
            + 'sleep="'+sleep_hour + ":" + sleep_minute +':00",' 
            +  date_updated="20'.....
```

Should I add a '0' before hours or minutes when they are lower than 10? Same for dates in case of months, days... Is there a way to create a time or timestamp variable and insert my variables?

Comment: You probably should try running your `UPDATE` using the MySQL command line interface, you will immediately see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Personally, I'd be getting rid of spurious plus signs in the SQL text, like the one before `sleep`. And sure. Go ahead and add a leading zero to get two digits if you want. That won't hurt anything. MySQL will accept two digits. Or, you could use the MySQL `MAKE_TIME` function. Whatever. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_maketime

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted. I have to change all the query to use '?' instead of plus signs, I just wanted to test it in a quicky way.